# Instagram dataset to CARTO via URL?

Tags: carto, token, instagram

I'm trying to do a one-time query of all points on Instagram with a given tag and visualize them in CARTO. It looks like CARTO allows you to connect a dataset via a URL. Does this mean I can simply insert the [URL from Instagram's Tag Endpoints API](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/tags/) and specify the tag name? Or is there another step I'm missing?

It looks like this would also require me to have an access token. I found this [GitHub page](https://github.com/adrianengine/jquery-spectragram/wiki/How-to-get-Instagram-API-access-token-and-fix-your-broken-feed) on how to create an access token and it seemed quite involved. Is there a simpler way to get an access token? I'm not really a developer and probably won't be creating any advanced applications, but I will likely want to pull data from time to time.

I just tested this out in CARTO using a token generated from [Pixel Union](http://instagram.pixelunion.net/) but it didn't work and generated the error message below. It looks like an issue having to do with the access token. Could this be that the Instagram account that the access token is associated with is private? Or would it be for some other reason?

ERROR: {"meta": {"code": 400, "error_type": "OAuthPermissionsException", "error_message": "This client has not been approved to access this resource."}}

Answer (score 2):

In order to retrieve data from Instagram's Tag Endpoints API you need more than just the ACCESS_TOKEN; each Endpoint has a specific scope, or permission, that you need to have in order to use it. In order to make the desired call, you'd need to have `public_content` access.

The Instagram API Platform is designed for app creation, specifically for developers. In order to use it, you have to sign up as a developer and register your app as a client, then have it reviewed so you can have the required login permissions granted.

If you recieve this login permission, your API call should work. If the data is formatted in a way that CARTO will understand and import directly is another issue, but it's possible that you'd have to format it in some way that can be used by CARTO.

**Long story short:** You need specific login permissions ("scopes") to use Instagram's API Platform. An ACCES_TOKEN is not enough.

Comment: Thank you! This is helpful. I'll look into this some more and see if it's worth it to become a developer.